# How to detect marquee text end listener?

Tags: android, marquee

I am using a text view and i have given elipzize = marquee, not what ever string i give to this text view scrolls horizontally but my problem is i need to detect if the marquee text is completed and want to load next string, i have given marque forever so i do not want to make the text keep running i want to change two things in the text so need to find out when it ends

see may xml here

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/push_message"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="#85000000"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                        android:textDirection="anyRtl"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        tools:ignore="EllipsizeMaxLines" />
```

Please tell me how to detect if the marquee text is end at the end of the marquee text i need to trigger some other evnet

Thank you in advance